# Data Manipulation in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I am new to spark and I am trying to achieve a certain data manipulation based on counts - the problem is like this - I have a text file with information that looks like this -

```
john, apple 
john, apple
john, orange
jill, apple
jill, orange
jill, orange
```

what I want to do is simple - I want to count the number of times each fruit appears for each person and divide that number by the total number of fruits among the two persons - so the outcome would look like this:

```
john, apple, 2, 3
jill, apple, 1, 3
john, orange, 1, 3
jill orange, 2, 3
```

Then I can divide row 3 by row 4 for this final product -

```
john, apple, 2, 3, 2/3
jill, apple, 1, 3, 1/3
john, orange, 1, 3, 1/3
jill orange, 2, 3, 2/3
```

I have tried a few things in `scala` like this -

```
var persons = sc.textFile("path_to_directory").map(_.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))
persons.map{case(person, fruit)=>((person, fruit), 1)}.reduceByKey(_+_).collect
```

The output of this provides -

```
((jill,orange),2)
((jill,apple),1)
((john,orange),1)
((john,apple),2)
```

This seems like a good start but then I don't know how to proceed from here. Any help or hints would be greatly appreciated!

**UPDATE:**

I have a proposed solution for this problem -

```
var persons = sc.textFile("path_to_directory").map(_.split(",")).map(x=>(x(0),x(1)))

var count = persons.map{case(name, fruit)=>((name,fruit),1)}.reduceByKey(_+_)

var total = persons.map{case(name, fruit)=>(fruit,1)}.reduceByKey(_+_)

var fruit = count.map{case((name, fruit), count)=>(fruit, (name, count))}

fruit.join(total).map{case((fruit,((name, count), total)))=>(name, fruit, count, total, count.toDouble/total.toDouble)}.collect.foreach(println)
```

The output for this scala code in spark is -

```
(jill,orange,2,3,0.6666666666666666)
(john,orange,1,3,0.3333333333333333)
(jill,apple,1,3,0.3333333333333333)
(john,apple,2,3,0.6666666666666666)
```

Comment: I think you cannot avoid doing two aggregation functions. One to count the frequencies of the first column and the second the frequencies of the pairs (as you don in your example). Then you can combine the two aggregates at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution:

```
def getFreqs(x: String, vals: Iterable[String]) = {
    val counts = vals.groupBy(identity).mapValues(_.size)
    val sum = counts.values.sum.toDouble
    counts.map { case (k, v) => (x, k, v, sum.toInt, v / sum) }
}

persons.groupByKey.flatMap { case(k, v) => getFreqs(k, v) }
```

And another:

```
val fruitsPerPerson = sc.broadcast(persons.countByKey)

persons.groupBy(identity).map { case (k, v) => {
    val sum: Float = fruitsPerPerson.value.get(k._1) match {
        case Some(x) => x
        case _ => 1
    }
    (k._1, k._2, v.size, sum.toInt, v.size / sum) 
}}
```

Both `groupByKey` and `groupBy` can be rather inefficient so if you're looking for a more robust solution you may consider using `combineByKey`:

```
def create(value: String) = Map(value -> 1)

def mergeVals(x: Map[String, Int], value: String) = {
    val count = x.getOrElse(value, 0) + 1
    x ++ Map(value -> count)
}

def mergeCombs(x: Map[String, Int], y: Map[String, Int]) = {
    val keys = x.keys ++ y.keys
    keys.map((k: String) => (k -> (x.getOrElse(k, 0) + y.getOrElse(k, 0)))).toMap
}

val counts = persons.combineByKey(create, mergeVals, mergeCombs)

counts.flatMap { case (x: String, counts: Map[String, Int]) =>  {
    val sum = counts.values.sum.toDouble
    counts.map { case (k: String, v: Int) => (x, k, v, sum.toInt, v / sum) }
}}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I am also new to scala could you maybe explain a little about what `vals: Iterable[String]` is used for and how it works in the code?

Comment: `groupByKey` transforms takes `(RDD[(K, T)] )` and returns  `RDD[(K Iterable[T])]`, co in your case you get `RDD[(String, Iterable[String])]`. Hence `vals: Iterable[String]`, as argument.